# Oracle REGEX_REPLACE function and capture groups

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a string that i would like to convert from a sequence of strings to a sequence of strings separated by a hyphen. Example

```
200400116828 --> 2004-001168-28
```

For String to be converted, the input string must follow these rules:

```
- Starts with a 1 or 2
- Followed by three digits
- Followed by 6 digits
- Followed by 2 digits
```

I use a Regex to extract the above groups from the input string to build the output string using the Regex '`^([12]\d{3})(\d{6})(\d{2})$`'

I managed to get it to work using the following query:

```
Select REGEXP_REPLACE(
            '200400116828','^([12]\d{3})(\d{6})(\d{2})$','\1-\2-\3'
          ) from dual;
```

**Output** - `2004-001168-28`

But i am confused by the following query also works but with a wrong output:

```
Select REGEXP_REPLACE(
            '200400116828','^([12]\d{3})(\d{6})(\d{2})$','\10-\11-\12'
          ) from dual;
```

**Output** - `20040-20041-20042`

Could somebody please explain the output of the 2nd query because to me it does not match the RegEx provide.

Comment: During Replace, `\10` is treated as `\1` followed by a `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is fine, you are confused with the replacement pattern.

Oracle regex engine is POSIX based and replacement patterns only support backreferences from 1 through 9. What can't be parsed as a backreference is parsed as literal text.

Hence, `\10-\11-\12` is parsed as Group 1 value, `0-`, Group 1 value, `1-`, Group 1 value, `2`.

Also, see [`regexp_replace` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

> The *`replace_string`* can contain up to 500 backreferences to subexpressions in the form `\n`, where `n` is a number from 1 to 9.

Comment: Ah that explains it. If i have a regex with more than 9 capture groups, how would i access the 10th, 11th etc groups?

Comment: @ziggy There is no way to reference the tenth backreference and further in Oracle regex. This limitation is documented.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.